# Customize itemize bullets

Tags: enumerate, itemize

I'm trying to create an ordered list that has a "collection" bullet at the end, as in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Some text.

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
\end{enumerate}

\begin{itemize}
    \renewcommand{\labelitemi}{3-5.}
    \item Items 3 through 5
\end{itemize}

Some more different text.
\end{document}
```

I've gotten this far, which seems like the correct way to do it.  However, the last item bullet point is aligned with the other items on the right edge, not the left edge, making it push out into the left margin.  I haven't found a solution to this part of it yet.

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to check the `enumitem` package and its interfaces to specify the horizontal spacing of lists.

Comment: Related: [Add second enumeration item on the same line?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/51086)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I unserstand well, you want this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

Some text.

\begin{enumerate}[align=left]
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item[3--5.] Items 3 through 5
\end{enumerate}

Some more different text. Some more different text. Some more different text. Some more different text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to continue the enumeration from 6, you can close the enumerate environment, then re-open  it, with

```
\begin{enumerate}[resume*, start=6]
\item …
\end{enumerate}
```

Adding the option `leftmargin=*`, make the list left margin equal to the left margin for the default label:

```
\begin{enumerate}[align=left, leftmargin=*]
    \item Item 1
    \item Item 2
    \item[3--5.] Items 3 through 5. Some more details. Some more details. Some more details. 
\end{enumerate}
```

and one obtains this alignment:

[image]

Comment: This is great, thanks.  I'm not sure why, but I had to add leftmargin=* as well.

Comment: This means the list left margin is the margin for a standard label, i.e.  longer labels can overflow into the item body zone.  I'll add an example of this possibility.